# Updating a list in a loop in python without using the append function.

Tags: python, list, loops

Hi there suppose I have;

```
a = np.array([1.,2.])
b = np.array([3.,4.])
r = []
... 
for i in range(10)
    b*i
    r[i] = ((a[0]+b[0]) - (a[1] - b[1]))
    ...
i = i+1
```

The code is meant to take arrays a and b and perform addition and subtraction on elements from them, and place them into what I think should be a list, which in this case I've called r. (i.e so r[0] = 0, r[1] = 6 etc.)

I know this does not work, but I don't know why can someone tell me what I should define 'r' to be?

I'd rather avoid using something like;

```
r.append(...)
```

The end goal is to plot r vs i , should I therefore construct both lists and then plot them against eachother, or should I include it in the loop somehow.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with `r.append()`?

Comment: What is the intended behavior of the line `b*i`? If np arrays are anything like regular lists, that line won't have any effect.

Comment: This has a very strong [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) smell to it. But answering why `[].append()` is bad will help.

Comment: Hi, I was just curious of other ways to do it. If append is the best way then I will do it that way. @Kevin , you are probably right - this code is solely to learn so that line may well do nothing.

Comment: As for 'X-Y indication'. I have done a bit of code which works using .append , I just know there are ways to do it like this and I was wondering how it could be achieved as I am not familiar with these additional methods.

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehensions, as an example, I'm going to rewrite your whole for loop and r = [] into this:

```
r = [((a[0]+(b*i)[0]) - (a[1] - (b*i)[1])) for i in range(1,10)]
```

This does the same, more readable, much more faster.

Comment: I like the list comprehension idea, but I believe `b*i[0]` will cause an error, because it's interpreted as `b*(i[0])` rather than `(b*i)[0]`.

Comment: well my bad then, fixing it asap